# How to get rows with duplicate values with a better performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get rows that has duplicate values in a column. This is the SQL:

```
select * from `match` where `match`.`homeTeam` in 
(select `matchView`.`homeTeam` from `matchView` 
group by `matchView`.`homeTeam` having (count(0) > 1))
 order by `match`.`homeTeam`
```

It does the job, but takes 15 seconds. What can I do to improve its speed

EDIT: explain sql results:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     match   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2691    Using where; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  match   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2691    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Could you add `exaplain` result and tables structures?

Comment: Do you already have an index in the column?

Comment: @dragoste I added explain sql on phpmyadmin if that is what you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select `match`.* 
from `match` join (select `matchView`.`homeTeam` 
                   from `matchView` 
                   group by `matchView`.`homeTeam` 
                    having (count(0) > 1)) watches ON `match`.`homeTeam`=watches.`homeTeam`
order by `match`.`homeTeam`
```

Comment: wow! same results with 0.07 second. Didnt know the join was so usefull. Cant vote up sorry.